# Energy saving got natural world

Tags: electricity

If i send small amount of electricity (eg.10v) given input of circuit,can i using stepup transformer,now get 30v then it separate 10v to output,10v to input of circuit,10v using backup for inputer.i dont know it is possible are not, if is it possible we save energy in this world.[image]

Comment: I invented a perpetual energy source, but could not make it pay...

Comment: It is great that you are trying to solve the world energy problem, but have you tried reading a textbook on physics or electricity as the first step?

Comment: Have you considered the losses each time you go through an iteration?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't and here is why:

In an ideal step-up transformer, as you step *up* the voltage, you step *down* the current.   This means that the *input power* (input current times input voltage) equals the *output power* (output current times output voltage) and you therefore cannot create *more power* by sending it through a step-up transformer.

Comment: Are there any losses or is this a "perfect" step-up transformer?

Comment: this one is perfect ("ideal") as specified; the truth is if course worse than that because transformers are slightly dissipative. -NN

Answer (score 0):

No, laws of thermodynamics say energy cannot be created nor destroyed, only transformed.

amounts of energy are in watts, or volt amps, not just voltage.

but a good try.